# CompareTo incorrect return value

Tags: java, return, compareto

First and Foremost, I must mention after reading lots of questions and tutorials and watching some videos, still the problem is not resolved.

I am an intermediate programmer in Java, and I have written some codes for comparing elements in a priority queue, in which elements are kept like [Comparable element, int priority]. Obviously, the higher priority would be popped.

the problem is: 
I modified the code to have the first element with highest priority, and it does NOT work! I have narrowed it down that when comparing the first 2 elements, the compareTo method returns 0, which it should NOT, consequently the code fails!

this is the class that has the push of O(1) and Pop of O(n):

```
public class PriorityQueueU<T> 
    {
            public class PriorityPair implements Comparable
            {
                public Comparable  element;
                public Comparable  priority;

                public PriorityPair(Comparable  element, int  priority){
                    this.element = element; 
                    this.priority = priority; 
                }

                public Comparable<T> getElemet(){
                    return this.element; 
                }

                public Comparable<T> getPriority(){
                    return this.priority; 
                }

                public int compareTo(Comparable  a)
                {
                    PriorityPair p2 = (PriorityPair)a;
                    return ((Comparable)priority).compareTo(p2.priority);
                }

                public String toString(){

                    String s1 = this.element.toString(); 
                    String s2 = this.priority.toString(); 
                    String res = "[ " + s1 + ", " +  s2 + " ]"   ;
                    return res; 
                }

                public int compareTo(Object o)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 0;
                }

            }
            private LinkedList data;

            public PriorityQueueU()
            {
                data = new LinkedList();
            }


            public void pushUnsorted(Comparable<T>  o, int priority)
            {
                PriorityPair paired = new PriorityPair(o, priority);  
                data.addLast(paired);
            }

            public Comparable  popUnsorted()
            {


                int index = 0; 

                for (int i = 0; i < this.data.size() - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (((PriorityPair) this.data.get(i)).compareTo(this.data.get(i + 1)) < 0)
                    {
                        index = i + 1; 
                    }
                }

                PriorityPair pp = (PriorityQueueU<T>.PriorityPair) this.data.get(index); 
                this.data.deleteIt(index);
                return pp.getElemet(); 
            }




            public String toString(){
                return this.data.toString();  
            }

        }
}
```

and this is the code that would test the behavior:

```
 PriorityQueueU<T> unSortedPQ = new PriorityQueueU<>();


            unSortedPQ.pushUnsorted( (Comparable<T>) "a", 1000);
            unSortedPQ.pushUnsorted((Comparable<T>) "b", 200);
            unSortedPQ.pushUnsorted((Comparable<T>) "j", 900);
            unSortedPQ.pushUnsorted((Comparable<T>) "r", 9);
            unSortedPQ.pushUnsorted((Comparable<T>) "z", 6);

            System.out.println("the UNsorted priority Q: ");
            System.out.println(unSortedPQ);

            System.out.println("*#------------------END OF PUSH-----------------#*");
            System.out.println();



            System.out.println("the priority Q: " + unSortedPQ);
            System.out.println("popped item is: " + unSortedPQ.popUnsorted());

    //      System.out.println("top of the priority queue is: " + uPriorityQueueU.top());
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("the UNsorted priority Q: ");
            System.out.println(unSortedPQ);

            System.out.println("*#------------------END OF POP-----------------#*");
            System.out.println();
```

MANY thanks in advance.

P.S. bear in mind that maybe I was wrong and the problem was somewhere else! 
current behavior: it pops j, which is the second highest element in the list. I already know that when popping, the element must be deleted as well from the priority queue, which is stored in a linked list. I made sure deletion in linked list is correctly working, but don't hesitate to ask for the code if necessary.

Comment: You have two `compareTo` methods, which definitely seems wrong.

Comment: And, to add to Marvin's comment, your comparison is implemented in the wrong `compareTo` method

Comment: Dear Robin,
I was aware that it is implemented in the wrong one, the problem is why! 
thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't use raw types!

Answer (score 1):

In order for `compareTo` to work, you should implement the method provided by the `Comparable` interface.

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

As we see from the code above, `Copmarable` supports generics. If you do not specify what type of objects you want to compare (leave it as it is), it will default to `Object`, which it does (that's from your code):

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
}
```

So you either use generics or write logic for `compareTo(Object o)`.

Comment: Dear Cargeh, 
I had written the logic for it, but it is not implemented; and when I delete the wrong compareTo method, there is error coming up.
I am well aware this is incorrect, but I don't know how to enforce the method use the correct method instead of the second one. that's the problem!

Comment: Dear @Kayvan, as I said, try using generics. `... implements Comparable<Comparable>`, then it should use the method you've written. Otherwise it defaults to `Object`, as I stated above. Please, re-read my answer.